# Unable to reset MariaDB root password

Tags: password, mysql, mariadb

I am doing:

```
$ sudo vim /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf
```

then adding

skip-grant-tables

then

```
$ sudo service mysqld restart
```

then

```
$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password:
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 30
Server version: 10.1.47-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Ubuntu 18.04

Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

MariaDB [(none)]> use mysql;
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Database changed
MariaDB [mysql]> update user SET PASSWORD=PASSWORD('sa') WHERE USER='root';
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [mysql]> flush privileges;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [mysql]> exit
Bye
```

then

```
$ sudo vim /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf
```

then removing

```
skip-grant-tables
```

then

```
$ sudo service mysqld restart
```

then

```
$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password:
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

Why?

If I am trying to

```
MariaDB [mysql]> SET PASSWORD FOR root = PASSWORD('sa');
ERROR 1290 (HY000): The MariaDB server is running with the --skip-grant-tables option so it cannot execute this statement
```

Answer (score 1):

MySQL credentials can't be managed by updating mysql.user table.

To change a user password run the following script:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'MyNewPass';
```